# use GNU sort to sort by a single key / prevent unwanted sorting of other keys

Tags: sort

I have a file which contains already ordered data and I'd like to re-order the file according to the values in one key, without destroying the order of the data in the other keys.

How do I prevent GNU sort from performing row sorting based on the values of keys I have not specified, or how do I specify to GNU sort to ignore a range of keys when sorting?

File data.txt:

```
1 Don't
2 C 
1 Sort
2 B
1 Me
2 A
```

Expected output:

```
1 Don't
1 Sort
1 Me
2 C
2 B
2 A
```

Command:

```
sort -k 1,1 <data.txt
```

Result: unwanted sorting I didn't ask for:

```
1 Don't
1 Me
1 Sort
2 A
2 B
2 C
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need a *stable sort*. From `man sort`:

```
-s, --stable
       stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison
```

viz.:

```
$ sort -sk 1,1 <data.txt
1 Don't
1 Sort
1 Me
2 C 
2 B
2 A
```

Note that you probably also want a `-n` or `--numeric-sort` if your key is numeric (for example, you may get unexpected results when comparing 10 to 2 with the default - lexical - sort order). In which case it's just a matter of doing:

```
sort -sn <data.txt
```

No need to extract the first field as the numeric interpretation of the  whole line will be the same as the one of the first field.

Comment: [Stability in sorting algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1517793/995714) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability

Comment: I read the docs but the proper definition of "stable" evaded my attention.  Thanks for the quick, concise, and well cited response.  The real data's first key is a localized string, so numeric wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

For (non-GNU) `sort` implementations that lack a `-s` option, you can always do:

```
<data.txt awk '{print NR "\t" $0}' | sort -n -k 2,2 -k 1,1 | cut -f 2-
```

That is, prepend the line number to make it the second sort key, and strip it afterwards.