# Sort by the first column only

Tags: linux, sort

Why sort changes second and third line when it should do nothing in below input file for given options?

```
$ cat test1
1 4
2 5 
2 1
3 6

$ sort -n -k 1,1 test1
1 4
2 1
2 5 
3 6
```

Comment: You need a *stable sort* - see for example [use GNU sort to sort by a single key / prevent unwanted sorting of other keys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374066/use-gnu-sort-to-sort-by-a-single-key-prevent-unwanted-sorting-of-other-keys)

Answer (score 3):

That's the last-resort comparison that compares full lines lexically when they otherwise compare equally based on the sort key specification.

With the GNU implementation of `sort`, you can add the `-s` option to disable that last-resort comparison. The GNU `sort` sorting algorithm being *stable*, you'll get the original order in the input, so:

```
sort -s -n -k1,1
```

Or just:

```
sort -sn
```

(as the comparison is numerical, whether it's the full line or the first field that is converted to a number for comparison won't make a difference).

Answer (score 1):

Run with the debug option. The first underscore is the main sort, the next are auxiliary

```
sort -n -k1,1 --debug test1
sort: text ordering performed using simple byte comparison
1 4
_
___
2 1
_
___
2 5 
_
____
3 6
_
___
```

Note that the second underscore starts at the first field!
To make it easier to understand, you can perceive it like this:

```
1 (1 4)
2 (2 1)  
2 (2 5)
3 (3 6)
```